# font setup cochineal for text and stix2 for math

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math

Experienced coder but newbie on latex, I can't wrap my head around the way font and font packages behaves !

I would be glad to have a working snippet, but if you have some generic advises about the philosophy of the system, I take.

I'm trying to use the *cochineal font for all text, and the stix2 font for all math*. My first attempt was :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\setmathfont(STIX2Math.otf)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

where I got:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \setmathfont

l.7 \setmathfont
                (STIX2Math.otf)
```

which seems strange, since this control sequence is used by me on numerous other templates! So I tried some other random combinations, and also black magic, and rabbit paws, in vain.

How can I set a math font and a text font? How does fallback works? Where do the Latin and Greek letters come from in math, from the main font? And about `unicode-math` should I still use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with it? And what's the logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use Cochineal for text and STIX2 for math is probably to use `cochineal` and `newtxmath` with `stix2` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage[stix2]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
A test to see the cochineal text font.
\[
f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \,\mathrm{d}\zeta.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, in your example, it's not surprising that `\setmathfont` is undefined: this command is defined by the `unicode-math` package, which is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you ! it seems to do the job :) I'm still struggling to understand what is the role of newtxmath and why `\usepackage{stix2} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[stix2]{newtxmath}` gives different symbols for integrals or sums... (I preferred the stix2 ones :D)

Answer (score 2):

Under 2023 `texlive` the font is `STIXTwo`.  I can also see the file `cochineal.fontspec` in `texlive` hence I can make the undocumented `\setmainfont{cochineal}` call. I am stealing the example of @Vincent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{cochineal}
% This also works
% \usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}

\begin{document}


A \strong{test} to see the \textit{cochineal} text font with
\textbf{\textit{STIXTwo}} math.

\[
\sum {f(z)} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta - z} \,\mathrm{d}\zeta.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: stixtwo + cochineal]

It's another matter if the difference between the x-sizes and overall styles of the two fonts can be matched satisfactorily enough just to have that cute `stixtwo` inline integral sign.

[image: x size differences]

Here is the code for the above example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{cochineal}
% \setmainfont{STIXTwoText}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath}%[Scale = MatchAveragecase]

\newcommand{\comp}[1]{\emph{#1}$#1$}

\begin{document}
A test to see if the \textbf{cochineal} text font with
\textbf{STIXTwo} math match well each other.\medskip

\comp{a}\comp{b}\comp{c}\comp{d}\comp{e}\comp{f}\comp{g}
\comp{h}\comp{i}\comp{j}\comp{k}\comp{l}\comp{m}\comp{n}
\comp{o}\comp{p}\comp{q}\comp{r}\comp{s}\comp{t}\comp{u}
\comp{v}\comp{w}\comp{x}\comp{y}\comp{z} and how about \emph{v}$\nu$?

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{thm}
Let $a,b,c$ the sides of a right angle triangle, where $a$ and $b$ are
the legs and $c$ is the hypotenuse. We then have $a^2+b^2=c^2$. 
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  Consider the set $J$ (Jordan measurable!), and let $d$ denote the
  linear distance. Then the average distance between $J$ and $J+i$ is
  less than $2$, that is, $\int_I d(J,J+i)di<2$, confirming the
  conjecture of Erdős.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```